# i have a school laptop can the school see my history if i use a vpn?

Tags: web-application, vpn, historical

i have a vpn, can the school still see what i search? and when in turn it on i can go on sites that been blocked. i haven tried inappropriate sites but game sites work and social media sites which the school also blocked.

Comment: They definitely can if they want to or if they have suspicion that you’re viewing websites you’re not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that the VPN does is connect you to the school's network through the internet.  If there is software on the laptop that reports your searches, the network connection will not change that.  That software may not report until you connect via the VPN, but even if that's the case it will report when you connect to the school's network.

Without knowing what software is on the laptop and the parameters that are set for it, the question is difficult to answer.  So I'll make some assumptions.  Assuming that there is software on the laptop that monitors on and reports your search history at all times, then the answer is yes, the school will be able to find out what you search.  If there isn't some kind of monitoring software or the monitoring software is not set to monitor searches, then the answer is no, but not due to the presence of your VPN.

Generally assume that no reasonable expectation of privacy exists on a computer that you did not pay for.  In other words, if you don't own it, assume that the owner can and will see everything you do on it.

Comment: we must stop answering these questions. This exact question came up about 20 times already.